# namespace global variable losing value (C++)

Tags: c++, variables, static, namespaces, global

So in my namespace's .h file, I have

```
namespace wtvr{
    static Matrix m;
    void LoadIdentity(void);
};
```

and in its .cpp file, I have

```
namespace wtvr{
    void LoadIdentity(void){
        m = Identity();
        m.display();// trace for debugging
    }
};
```

else where in the main program

```
wtvr::LoadIdentity();
wtvr::m.display();
```

The first display() prints the identity matrix to the screen from within the LoadIdentity() function, but the second, which is after the function returns, displays all zeros.
Why are my values disappearing?
Is there a different way I should be making my global?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared `static Matrix m;` in the header file. This means that each .cpp file that includes that header will get its own version of `m`.

instead you need to make it a global (although namespace-scoped) variable.

In the header file:

```
namespace wtvr{
extern Matrix m;
};
```

In any of the .cpp files:

```
namespace wtvr{
Matrix m;
};
```

Comment: what if we want to initialize with a value? just assign it in the above cpp file definition?

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the variable as `static`, which means each translation unit (.cpp file) has its own copy of it. You probably meant this:

.h file:

```
namespace wtvr{

extern Matrix m;  //declare for use from everywhere
void LoadIdentity(void);

}
```

.cpp file:

```
namespace wtvr{

Matrix m;  //define in exactly one .cpp file

void LoadIdentity(void)
{
  m = Identity();
  m.display();// trace for debugging
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a different way you should be making your global.

In the .h file:

```
extern Matrix m;
```

In its .cpp file:

```
Matrix m;
void LoadIdentity(void)
{
    m = Identity();
    m.display();
}
```

No other file needs to change. `static` in file scope means that each file gets its own copy of the variable that isn't linked with other files' copies of the variable, which is the opposite of what you want.